# How can I make a Python Wheel from an existing native library?

Tags: python, python-wheel

Suppose I have a native shared library (.dll or .so), built independently of any Python mechanism, and a Python module using ctypes to interface to the library. Is there a way that I can build those into a .whl package? If so, how?

Assuming this is possible, I think I'd need the wheel package installed and to use `python setup.py bdist_wheel` but what would my setup.py need to look like?

I'd like to do this so I can upload Wheels for various platforms into a private package index and be able to pip install the appropriate one for the platform I'm on.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Here is a way. For an example, this uses libeay32.dll to expose an md5 package.

The project structure is:

```
MD5
│   setup.py
│
└───md5
    __init__.py   
    libeay32.dll
```

The setup.py is:

```
from setuptools import setup, Distribution
 
 
class BinaryDistribution(Distribution):
    def has_ext_modules(foo):
        return True


setup(
    name='md5',
    version='1.0',
    description='MD5 Library',
    packages=['md5'],
    package_data={
        'md5': ['libeay32.dll'],
    },
    distclass=BinaryDistribution
)
```

A couple of things to note:

1. The DLL is listed as package data so that it will be included in the wheel.
2. A [custom distclass is used](http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2014/1/27/python-on-wheels/) that indicates this wheel has an extension module, and since the wheel is being built on Windows, that this is a win32 wheel.

The Python ctypes code can load the DLL relative to itself (this code is in `__init.py__`):

```
lib_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'libeay32.dll')
lib = CDLL(lib_path)
```

After having installed 'wheel' with pip, I can run `python setup.py bdist_wheel` to produce dist\md5-1.0-cp34-none-win32.whl. I happen to be using cpython 3.4, but if you want a universal wheel, you can add `options={"bdist_wheel": {"universal": True}}` into the setup call.

Now I can create and activate a new virtual environment, pip install md5-1.0-cp34-none-win32.whl, and use my package:

```
>>> import md5
>>> md5.digest('hello')
'8d11aa0625ce42cfe9429d5e93b5ab0a'
```

Comment: Does this work on Linux, where LD_LIBRARY_PATH matters to see and load .so file?

Comment: You can also pass `has_ext_modules` as an argument to `setup()`. It still expects a callable. Add `has_ext_modules=lambda : True` as a `setup()` argument and you can skip `distclass`.

Comment: The https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject/blob/master/setup.cfg which was referenced no longer builds a universal wheel. I've updated with a working alternative.

Answer (score 11):

Although the chosen answer was correct at the time of writing, [this pull request](https://github.com/pypa/wheel/commit/9fc2c53cfe6a14a78c09a0c8863de2d8ddaadcf8) broke this functionality.

I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36886459/1373380) correctly solves this problem in newer versions of the wheel package.

(Would have added this as a comment, but lack the reputation needed.)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up -- I've updated the answer to use `has_ext_modules` rather than `is_pure`.

Comment: The link to the pull request is dead. I think it may have been [this commit](https://github.com/pypa/wheel/commit/9fc2c53cfe6a14a78c09a0c8863de2d8ddaadcf8) on github, but I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 1):

Use `cibuildwheel`, this is the solution from `pypa`, the team behind `pip`.

`cibuildwheel` can build wheels with native libraries, and it automatically fix issues like `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and incorporate the dll/so files into the bdist wheel.