# How to package a linked DLL and a pyd file into one self contained pyd file?

Tags: python, windows, dll, cython

I am building a python module with Cython that links against a DLL file. In order to succesfully import my module I need to have the DLL in the Windows search path. Otherwise, the typical error message is:

`ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.`

Is there a way to packaged the DLL directly into the produced pyd file to make the distribution easier?

One example of this is with the OpenCV distribution, where a (huge) pyd file is distributed and is the only file needed for the Python bindings to work.

Comment: The DLL can be in the same directory as the extension module. Python loads a .pyd extension using `LoadLibraryEx` with `LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH`.

Comment: I am looking for a way to merge both file into 1, skipping the need to have the DLL in the search path.

Comment: Not sure, but I think you might be able to use ctypes.cdll or ctypes.windll to load your library first, and then it will find the instance of it, e.g. temp = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('path_to_dll').  Alternatively, from within your pyd, you could access os.environ() to update the program's PATH before trying to load the DLL.

Comment: If you have the source for the other DLL, you could certainly create a makefile to link them together.  Not sure if there are any packages that let you relink.

Comment: That is the relink way I am looking for : )

Answer (score 10):

Python's packaging & deployment is still a pain point for many of us. There is just not a silver bullet. Here are several methods:

---

### 1. OpenCV build method

The method is decribed here : https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_bindings/py_bindings_basics/py_bindings_basics.html#bindings-basics

> OpenCV generates these wrapper functions automatically from the C++
>   headers using some Python scripts which are located in
>   modules/python/src2.

Basically it parse the header files and generate the `static PyObject` keywords whenever it's needed. Once the header are created appropriately, it just call `python setup`.  Honestly, it might work, but I would not advise this method.

### 2. Makefiles

If you already use Makefile, just create a rule to place your lib accordinlgy. Example, from my own code :

> setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
setup(name='sha1_hmac', version='1.0',  \
      ext_modules=[Extension('sha1_hmac',
                             library_dirs=['C:\MinGW\lib'],
                             sources= ['../tools/sha1.c','sha1_hmac.c'])])
```

> Makefile

```
# The hmac generation used by the webserver is done
# using the sha1.c implementation. There is a binding needed to
# glue the C code with the python script
libsha1_hmac:
ifeq ($(OS), Windows_NT)
    $(PYTHON) setup.py build --compiler=mingw32
else
    $(PYTHON) setup.py install --home=$(CURDIR)
endif

.PHONY: webserver
webserver:  libsha1_hmac
ifeq ($(OS), Windows_NT)
    mv $(shell find build -type f -name "sha1*.pyd") $(LIB)
else
    mv -f $(shell find $(LIB)/python -type f -name "sha1*.so") $(LIB)
endif
    $(PYTHON) hmac_server.py
```

### 3. Modern deployement tools

There are several new tools to deploy python applications, namely `wheels` which seem to gain traction. I don't use it, but it look like it can ease up your bundling problem :

- [How can I make a Python Wheel from an existing native library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24071491/how-can-i-make-a-python-wheel-from-an-existing-native-library)

Once it `wheeled`, you can install it like this : `pip install some-package.whl`

Comment: The openCV build method is producing the 1 file pyd result I am looking for (with access to the sources). For the method 2, I don't know if you can put the winDLL as source. In my case, I have them in libraries/library_dirs. For the method number 3, it seems like the DLL will be distributed but not merged into the final pyd.

Comment: Do you have access to the DLL source code ? or do you just link it, like user32.dll for example ? Only the first case works with OpenCV's method.

Comment: I do have access to the source code in my special case, and yes rebuild everything together in a unique build project would work.

However, I am looking for a solution in case there is no access to the source code.