# 'pip setup.py bdist_wheel' no longer builds forced non-pure wheels

Tags: python, windows, pypi, python-wheel, appveyor

I have a project that compiles with C extensions on Linux, but without
them on Windows. When I first generated the wheel files on Windows with `python setup.py bdist_wheel`, they became universal, and I could not upload them to PyPI as these universal wheels are preferred by `pip` for installation
over the `.tar.gz` uploads (the result from `python setup.py sdist`).

The trick around this was to specify in the `setup.py`:

```
Distribution.is_pure = lambda *args: False
```

or by subclassing `Distribution`:

```
class BinaryDistribution(Distribution):
    def is_pure(self):
        return False
```

and calling `setup()` in setup.py with the extra keyword argument  `distclass=BinaryDistribution,`.

This all worked fine on my VM running Windows XP 64 which has 32 and 64 bit versions of Python 2.6/2.7/3.3/3.4 and pypy installed just for this purpose. A simple batch file gives me:

```
dist/pkg-1.0-cp26-none-win32.whl
dist/pkg-1.0-cp26-none-win_amd64.whl
dist/pkg-1.0-cp27-none-win32.whl
dist/pkg-1.0-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl
dist/pkg-1.0-cp33-none-win32.whl
dist/pkg-1.0-cp33-none-win_amd64.whl
dist/pkg-1.0-cp34-none-win32.whl
dist/pkg-1.0-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl
```

and the appropriate package gets downloade and installed by `pip` when you run `pip` on Windows and when you run `pip` on Linux you get the

```
pkg-1.0.tar.gz
```

which includes the C sources which are compiled during installation.

The problem started with the fact that I don't have a spare Windows 7 licensed machine where I can install Python 3.5 (it doesn't install on the EOL XP). So I investigated [Appveyor](https://www.appveyor.com/) and created `appveyor.yml`:

```
environment:
  matrix:
    - PYTHON: C:\Python27
    - PYTHON: C:\Python33
    - PYTHON: C:\Python34
    - PYTHON: C:\Python35
    - PYTHON: C:\Python27-x64
    - PYTHON: C:\Python33-x64
      DISTUTILS_USE_SDK: '1'
    - PYTHON: 'C:\Python34-x64'
      DISTUTILS_USE_SDK: '1'
    - PYTHON: 'C:\Python35-x64'

install:
  - |
    %PYTHON%\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
    %PYTHON%\python.exe -m pip install wheel

build: off

test_script:
  - echo Skipped for now

after_test:
  - |
    %PYTHON%\python.exe setup.py bdist_wheel

artifacts:
  - path: dist\*
```

With the exact same source the result from the above eight calls to `python setup.py bdist_wheel` are:

```
pkg-1.0-py2-none-any.whl
pkg-1.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

And if you upload these to PyPI, Linux prefers them over the `.tar.gz` leading to non-inclusion of the C extension code.

What causes this, and how can I use Appveyor to build my `.whl` files (or at least the ones for Python 3.5?

Comment: I encoutered the exact same problem just now, with Windows 7 and python 3.5. Reverting to wheels 0.24.0 indeed fixes the problem. I tried looking for when wheel 0.25+ were released but cannot find the tag on the bitbucket repo. Any idea ?

Comment: @Overdrivr That was 2015-09-17. such info can easily be found by looking up wheel on [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wheel/0.25.0) (search on pypi itself will show you some older versions, or change the end of the URL from 0.26.0 yourself)

Comment: @Overdrivr look at my updated answer, with 0.28 and the `--plat-name` option you can now even generate the `.whl` files on a Linux machine if they are pure.

Answer (score 25):

I've just run into this issue myself with Python v2.7 and wheel v0.29.0 on Windows 7 x64, where I build a Python package with some pre-compiled extensions (complicated VisualStudio setup with SWIG and external DLLs).

After examining the source code I have found that overriding `Distribution.has_ext_modules` works (automatically includes platform name and ABI tag):

```
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools.dist import Distribution

DISTNAME = "packagename"
DESCRIPTION = ""
MAINTAINER = ""
MAINTAINER_EMAIL = ""
URL = ""
LICENSE = ""
DOWNLOAD_URL = ""
VERSION = '1.2'
PYTHON_VERSION = (2, 7)


# Tested with wheel v0.29.0
class BinaryDistribution(Distribution):
    """Distribution which always forces a binary package with platform name"""
    def has_ext_modules(foo):
        return True


setup(name=DISTNAME,
      description=DESCRIPTION,
      maintainer=MAINTAINER,
      maintainer_email=MAINTAINER_EMAIL,
      url=URL,
      license=LICENSE,
      download_url=DOWNLOAD_URL,
      version=VERSION,
      packages=["packagename"],

      # Include pre-compiled extension
      package_data={"packagename": ["_precompiled_extension.pyd"]},
      distclass=BinaryDistribution)
```

Answer (score 6):

An alternative that seems to do the same as the accepted answer but more concisely is this:

```
from setuptools import setup

DISTNAME = "packagename"
DESCRIPTION = ""
MAINTAINER = ""
MAINTAINER_EMAIL = ""
URL = ""
LICENSE = ""
DOWNLOAD_URL = ""
VERSION = '1.2'
PYTHON_VERSION = (2, 7)


setup(name=DISTNAME,
      description=DESCRIPTION,
      maintainer=MAINTAINER,
      maintainer_email=MAINTAINER_EMAIL,
      url=URL,
      license=LICENSE,
      download_url=DOWNLOAD_URL,
      version=VERSION,
      packages=["packagename"],

      # Include pre-compiled extension
      package_data={"packagename": ["_precompiled_extension.pyd"]},
      has_ext_modules=lambda: True)
```

Answer (score 5):

The difference, of course, is in the environment, on the correctly working Win XP there is an older version of the `wheel` package installed (0.24.0) whereas on Appveyor the latest and greatest (and broken) version 0.26 of wheel gets installed (0.25 is broken as well).

Changing the install stanza in the YAML file to fix the wheel version:

```
install:
  - |
    %PYTHON%\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
    %PYTHON%\python.exe -m pip install wheel==0.24
```

is enough to get this to work quickly.

You should however upgrade your the wheel package on your Linux box to version 0.28 and then use the new commandline option `--plat-name`:

```
python setup.py sdist
python2 setup.py bdist_wheel --plat-name win32
python2 setup.py bdist_wheel --plat-name win_amd64
python3 setup.py bdist_wheel --plat-name win32
python3 setup.py bdist_wheel --plat-name win_amd64
```

that will generate:

```
pkg-1.1.tar.gz
dist/pkg-1.1-py2-none-win32.whl
dist/pkg-1.1-py2-none-win32.whl
dist/pkg-1.1-py3-none-win_amd64.whl
dist/pkg-1.1-py3-none-win32.whl
dist/pkg-1.0-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl
```

which you can upload to PyPI and results in the correct (`.tar.gz`) file downloading on Linux and the appropriate wheel on Windows. By just making
sure that if the `--plat-name win...` is specified `setup()` is called with `ext_modules=None`. The resulting wheel files have minor  (line endings in 3 files and their SHA256SUM), but install normally on Windows.

**That way you no longer need to build these packages, that are essentially pure packages, on a Windows machine**

For me this change by *Nate Coraor* brings my total build time down from 15+ minutes to about 7 **seconds**