# How to force a python wheel to be platform specific when building it?

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py, python-wheel

I am working on a python2 package in which the `setup.py` contains some custom install commands. These commands actually build some Rust code and output some `.dylib` files that are moved into the python package.

An important point is that the Rust code is outside the python package.

`setuptools` is supposed to detect automatically if the python package is pure python or platform specific (if it contains some C extensions for instance).
In my case, when I run `python setup.py bdist_wheel`, the generated wheel is tagged as a pure python wheel: `<package_name>-<version>-py2-none-any.whl`.
This is problematic because I need to run this code on different platforms, and thus I need to generated one wheel per platform.

Is there a way, when building a wheel, to force the build to be platform specific ?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Here's the code that I usually look at from [uwsgi](https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/blob/085015b281ff3d0e81fa52cc9c2fc6c4e3917393/setup.py#L95-L99)

The basic approach is:

#### setup.py

```
# ...

try:
    from wheel.bdist_wheel import bdist_wheel as _bdist_wheel
    class bdist_wheel(_bdist_wheel):
        def finalize_options(self):
            _bdist_wheel.finalize_options(self)
            self.root_is_pure = False
except ImportError:
    bdist_wheel = None

setup(
    # ...
    cmdclass={'bdist_wheel': bdist_wheel},
)
```

The `root_is_pure` bit tells the wheel machinery to build a non-purelib (`pyX-none-any`) wheel.  You can also get [fancier](https://github.com/Yelp/dumb-init/blob/48db0c0d0ecb4598d1a6400710445b85d67616bf/setup.py#L11-L27) by saying there are *binary* platform-specific components but no *cpython abi* specific components.

Comment: Thanks a lot, exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: You can also do `super().finalize_options()` instead of `_bdist_wheel.finalize_options(self)`

Comment: @TobiasBergkvist when this answer was written python 2 support was still important and the `bdist_wheel` class was an old-style class

Answer (score 21):

The modules `setuptools`, `distutils` and `wheel` decide whether a python distribution is pure by checking if it has `ext_modules`.

If you build an external module on your own, you can still list it in `ext_modules` so that the building tools know it exists.  The trick is to provide an empty list of sources so that `setuptools` and `distutils` will not try to build it.  For example,

```py
setup(
    ...,
    ext_modules=[
        setuptools.Extension(
            name='your.external.module',
            sources=[]
        )
    ]
)
```

This solution worked better for me than patching the `bdist_wheel` command.  The reason is that `bdist_wheel` calls the `install` command internally and that command checks again for the existence of `ext_modules` to decide between `purelib` or `platlib` install. If you don't list the external module, you end up with the lib installed in a `purelib` subfolder inside the wheel. That causes problems when using `auditwheel repair`, which complains about the extensions being installed in a `purelib` folder.

Comment: This seems like a neat solution but causes an error in `distutils/_msvccompiler.py` on Windows builds, where I needed it :(

Comment: @Cas also add --skip-build option to bdist_* command at the setup.py call!

Comment: This doesn't work for me - even if passing an empty list for `sources`, setuptools tries to launch gcc.

Comment: This looked like the most elegant solution to me, but it then changes my python version from py3 to cpy38, any idea why or how to prevent it?

Answer (score 13):

Neither the root_is_pure trick nor the empty ext_modules trick worked for me, but after MUCH searching myself, I finally found a working solution in ['pip setup.py bdist_wheel' no longer builds forced non-pure wheels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35112511/pip-setup-py-bdist-wheel-no-longer-builds-forced-non-pure-wheels)

Basically, you override the 'has_ext_modules' function in the Distribution class, and set distclass to point to the overriding class.  At that point, setup.py will believe you have a binary distribution, and will create a wheel with the specific version of python, the ABI, and the current architecture.  As suggested by https://stackoverflow.com/users/5316090/py-j:

```
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools.dist import Distribution

DISTNAME = "packagename"
DESCRIPTION = ""
MAINTAINER = ""
MAINTAINER_EMAIL = ""
URL = ""
LICENSE = ""
DOWNLOAD_URL = ""
VERSION = '1.2'
PYTHON_VERSION = (2, 7)


# Tested with wheel v0.29.0
class BinaryDistribution(Distribution):
    """Distribution which always forces a binary package with platform name"""
    def has_ext_modules(foo):
        return True


setup(name=DISTNAME,
      description=DESCRIPTION,
      maintainer=MAINTAINER,
      maintainer_email=MAINTAINER_EMAIL,
      url=URL,
      license=LICENSE,
      download_url=DOWNLOAD_URL,
      version=VERSION,
      packages=["packagename"],

      # Include pre-compiled extension
      package_data={"packagename": ["_precompiled_extension.pyd"]},
      distclass=BinaryDistribution)
```

Answer (score 11):

You can also specify/spoof a specific platform name when building wheels by specifying a `--plat-name`:

```
python setup.py bdist_wheel --plat-name=manylinux1_x86_64
```

See the [Python Packaging User Guide](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/platform-compatibility-tags/#platform-tag) for the available platform tags on PyPI.

**Note:** take a look at something like [`cibuildwheel`](https://github.com/pypa/cibuildwheel) to build wheels for all platforms

Comment: what are all possible platform names ?

Comment: I have trouble finding an exact list for you. Technically you can give any argument you want, I think it's PyPI that chooses which tags it accepts when you upload it. Maybe https://packaging.python.org/specifications/platform-compatibility-tags/ can help you get started on finding an actual list?

Answer (score 2):

I find [Anthony Sottile's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45150383/3512538) great, but didn't work for me.

My case is that I have to enforce the wheel to be created for x86_64, but any python3, so making root impure actually caused my wheel to be py36-cp36 :(

A better way, IMO, in general is just to use `sys.argv`:

```py
from setuptools import setup
import sys

sys.argv.extend(['--plat-name', 'x86_64'])
setup(name='example-wheel')
```