# How do I build a py2 wheel package, when setup.py runs with a Python version 3 interpreter?

Tags: python, setuptools, packaging, python-wheel

I have a package that is supposed to be Python **version 2 only** but needs to be build running a version 3 interpreter.

The `setup.py` of this package looks something like hits:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    python_requires="<3.0, >=2.7.5",
    classifiers=[
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 2',
        'Intended Audience :: Developers',
    ],
    # ... more keyword arguments ... 
 )
```

If I call `python2 setup.py build bdist_wheel`, I get:

```
$ ls dist
mypackage-0.3.dev14-py2-none-any.whl
```

If I run it with a version 3 interpreter, i.e. `python3 setup.py build bdist_wheel`, I get:

```
$ ls dist
mypackage-0.3.dev14-py3-none-any.whl
```

I would have expected that regardless of the interpreter version, I will get a py2 package, because I specified it with `python_requires` (and in the tags). My package build server only has a Python 3 interpreter.

How can I build a wheel that targets Python 2 when running setuptools with a Python 3 interpreter? Is that at all possible? Does the `-py3-`/`-py2` in the filename mean something different than I think it does?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try passing the python-tag argument to bdist_wheel:

`python setup.py bdist_wheel --python-tag=py2`

It could also be passed as

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(options={'bdist_wheel':{'python_tag':'py2'}})
```

Or in `setup.cfg`

Comment: Nice solution, but unfortunately it gives me `'bdist_wheel' has no such option 'python-tag'`. Even after upgrading the  `wheel` package to `v0.33`.

Comment: Looks like it has to be python_tag (with an underscore) in the options={} dict.

Comment: It did. You were also missing a closing bracket, hope you don't mind I edited that.

Answer (score 4):

Modified from [How to force a python wheel to be platform specific when building it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45150304/how-to-force-a-python-wheel-to-be-platform-specific-when-building-it/45150383), this change to `setup.py` seems to work.

But I suspect there might be a less hacky way.

```
from setuptools import setup

try:
    from wheel.bdist_wheel import bdist_wheel as _bdist_wheel

    class bdist_wheel(_bdist_wheel):

        def finalize_options(self):
            _bdist_wheel.finalize_options(self)
            self.root_is_pure = False  # Mark us as not a pure python package

        def get_tag(self):
            python, abi, plat = _bdist_wheel.get_tag(self)
            python, abi = 'py2', 'none'  # python, abi, plat = 'py2', 'none', 'any'  
            return python, abi, plat
except ImportError:
    bdist_wheel = None

setup(      
    cmdclass={'bdist_wheel': bdist_wheel}
    # ... other keyword args ...
)
```

**Edit:**

With this solution the platform (`plat`) seems to change, because the resulting filename ends in `-py2-none-linux_x86_64.whl`.

I suspect that is a consequence of `self.root_is_pure = False`. Since I have no binaries in my package I assume it's safe to set the platform to `any` ant pure to `True`.

**Edit2:**

Another possible solution:

```
import sys
import setuptools

if 'bdist_wheel' in sys.argv:
    if not any(arg.startswith('--python-tag') for arg in sys.argv):
        sys.argv.extend(['--python-tag', 'py2'])

setuptools.setup(
    # ...
)
```