# How to specify CPU Architecture of a Python package in setup.py?

Tags: python, pip, setup.py, python-packaging, python-wheel

I wanted my package to be only available on 32bit and 64bit windows 10, how can i do this via setup.py ?

I already tried adding those classifiers for windows 10 and win32 environment, but its still generating a package with "none-any" in its wheel name.

I needed it to be something like "win-amd64-x86"(don't remember exactly). I have seen several other packagees with similar naming scheme.

I know i can manually rename the wheel file to do what i want but what is the proper way to do this ?

*In some PEP document i read that `Supported-Platforms:` argument is what i need but i don't know what are possible options to it and where do i put this argument ?*

Comment: Why do you want to restrict platforms if you don't have to? `wheel` will figure out arch restrictions depending on whether platform-specific binaries are packaged in your code or not. it sounds like you just build a [pure python package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45976946/what-is-pure-python), which should work on any arch - as `wheel` is telling you. If you are still convinced that you need to set it manually, is this here what you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45150304/how-to-force-a-python-wheel-to-be-platform-specific-when-building-it

Comment: My package is not Pure Python, its more of a Python wrapper around c# application, and it only works on Windows 10 (x86/amd64). Wheel didn't automatically detect Anything and produce whl file narked as "none-any", due to this i am even able to install it from pip on android (aarch64/armv8 cpu), which I don't want to happen.

Comment: then, if you can make the post I linked work for you, could you either suggest it as dupe target, or post your modifications as a self-answer? I'm afraid this question might be too specific to be reliably solved by anyone that isn't you.

Comment: Actually I have solved it already, and even forgot that I asked this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coudn't make it "Win 10 Only", but for "Windows Only", it can be done by using `--plat-name` argument to setup.py

For 32 bit Windows :-

```
python setup.py bdist_wheel --plat-name win32
```

For 64 bit Windows :-

```
python setup.py bdist_wheel --plat-name win_amd64
```

Also See : [How to force a python wheel to be platform specific when building it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45150304/14976549)