# legacy-install-failure × Encountered error while trying to install package- lxml

Tags: python, windows, numpy, pip, lxml

I am trying to install [harwest](https://pypi.org/project/harwest/) on my win11 laptop with AMD in it.

When I try to install it using `pip install harwest` I am getting the following output

```
Collecting harwest
  Using cached harwest-0.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (17 kB)
Collecting beautifulsoup4==4.8.2
  Using cached beautifulsoup4-4.8.2-py3-none-any.whl (106 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.10\site-packages (from harwest) (2.28.2)
Requirement already satisfied: gitdb2 in c:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.10\site-packages (from harwest) (4.0.2)
Collecting gitpython==3.0.6
  Using cached GitPython-3.0.6-py3-none-any.whl (451 kB)
Collecting lxml
  Using cached lxml-4.9.2.tar.gz (3.7 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: soupsieve>=1.2 in c:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.10\site-packages (from beautifulsoup4==4.8.2->harwest) (2.4)
Requirement already satisfied: gitdb>=4.0.1 in c:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.10\site-packages (from gitdb2->harwest) (4.0.10)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.10\site-packages (from requests->harwest) (2022.12.7)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in c:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.10\site-packages (from requests->harwest) (1.26.14)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<4,>=2 in c:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.10\site-packages (from requests->harwest) (3.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in c:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.10\site-packages (from requests->harwest) (3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: smmap<6,>=3.0.1 in c:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.10\site-packages (from gitdb>=4.0.1->gitdb2->harwest) (5.0.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: lxml
  Building wheel for lxml (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [102 lines of output]
      Building lxml version 4.9.2.
      Building without Cython.
      Building against pre-built libxml2 andl libxslt libraries
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310
      creating build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\builder.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\cssselect.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\doctestcompare.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\ElementInclude.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\pyclasslookup.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\sax.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\usedoctest.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\_elementpath.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\__init__.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      creating build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\__init__.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\includes
      creating build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\builder.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\clean.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\defs.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\diff.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\ElementSoup.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\formfill.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\html5parser.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\soupparser.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\usedoctest.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\_diffcommand.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\_html5builder.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\_setmixin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\__init__.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\html
      creating build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\isoschematron
      copying src\lxml\isoschematron\__init__.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\isoschematron
      copying src\lxml\etree.h -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\etree_api.h -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\lxml.etree.h -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\lxml.etree_api.h -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\etree.pyx -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\objectify.pyx -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\apihelpers.pxi -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\classlookup.pxi -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\cleanup.pxi -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\debug.pxi -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\docloader.pxi -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\dtd.pxi -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\extensions.pxi -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\iterparse.pxi -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\nsclasses.pxi -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\objectpath.pxi -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\parser.pxi -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\parsertarget.pxi -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\proxy.pxi -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\public-api.pxi -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\readonlytree.pxi -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\relaxng.pxi -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\saxparser.pxi -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\schematron.pxi -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\serializer.pxi -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\xinclude.pxi -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\xmlerror.pxi -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\xmlid.pxi -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\xmlschema.pxi -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\xpath.pxi -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\xslt.pxi -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\xsltext.pxi -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\includes\c14n.pxd -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\config.pxd -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\dtdvalid.pxd -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\etreepublic.pxd -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\htmlparser.pxd -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\relaxng.pxd -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\schematron.pxd -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\tree.pxd -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\uri.pxd -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\xinclude.pxd -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\xmlerror.pxd -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\xmlparser.pxd -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\xmlschema.pxd -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\xpath.pxd -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\xslt.pxd -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\etree_defs.h -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\lxml-version.h -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\includes
      creating build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\isoschematron\resources
      creating build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng
      copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng\iso-schematron.rng -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng
      creating build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
      copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\RNG2Schtrn.xsl -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
      copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\XSD2Schtrn.xsl -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
      creating build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
      copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_abstract_expand.xsl -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
      copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_dsdl_include.xsl -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
      copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_schematron_message.xsl -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
      copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_schematron_skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
      copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_svrl_for_xslt1.xsl -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
      copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\readme.txt -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
      running build_ext
      building 'lxml.etree' extension
      error: --plat-name must be one of ('win32', 'win-amd64', 'win-arm32', 'win-arm64')
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for lxml
  Running setup.py clean for lxml
Failed to build lxml
Installing collected packages: lxml, beautifulsoup4, gitpython, harwest
  Running setup.py install for lxml ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for lxml did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [104 lines of output]
      Building lxml version 4.9.2.
      Building without Cython.
      Building against pre-built libxml2 andl libxslt libraries
      running install
      C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310
      creating build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\builder.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\cssselect.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\doctestcompare.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\ElementInclude.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\pyclasslookup.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\sax.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\usedoctest.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\_elementpath.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\__init__.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      creating build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\__init__.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\includes
      creating build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\builder.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\clean.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\defs.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\diff.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\ElementSoup.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\formfill.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\html5parser.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\soupparser.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\usedoctest.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\_diffcommand.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\_html5builder.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\_setmixin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\__init__.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\html
      creating build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\isoschematron
      copying src\lxml\isoschematron\__init__.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\isoschematron
      copying src\lxml\etree.h -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\etree_api.h -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\lxml.etree.h -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\lxml.etree_api.h -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\etree.pyx -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\objectify.pyx -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\apihelpers.pxi -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\classlookup.pxi -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\cleanup.pxi -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\debug.pxi -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\docloader.pxi -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\dtd.pxi -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\extensions.pxi -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\iterparse.pxi -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\nsclasses.pxi -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\objectpath.pxi -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\parser.pxi -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\parsertarget.pxi -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\proxy.pxi -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\public-api.pxi -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\readonlytree.pxi -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\relaxng.pxi -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\saxparser.pxi -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\schematron.pxi -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\serializer.pxi -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\xinclude.pxi -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\xmlerror.pxi -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\xmlid.pxi -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\xmlschema.pxi -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\xpath.pxi -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\xslt.pxi -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\xsltext.pxi -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml
      copying src\lxml\includes\c14n.pxd -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\config.pxd -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\dtdvalid.pxd -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\etreepublic.pxd -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\htmlparser.pxd -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\relaxng.pxd -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\schematron.pxd -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\tree.pxd -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\uri.pxd -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\xinclude.pxd -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\xmlerror.pxd -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\xmlparser.pxd -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\xmlschema.pxd -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\xpath.pxd -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\xslt.pxd -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\etree_defs.h -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\lxml-version.h -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\includes
      creating build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\isoschematron\resources
      creating build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng
      copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng\iso-schematron.rng -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng
      creating build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
      copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\RNG2Schtrn.xsl -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
      copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\XSD2Schtrn.xsl -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
      creating build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
      copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_abstract_expand.xsl -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
      copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_dsdl_include.xsl -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
      copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_schematron_message.xsl -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
      copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_schematron_skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
      copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_svrl_for_xslt1.xsl -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
      copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\readme.txt -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
      running build_ext
      building 'lxml.etree' extension
      error: --plat-name must be one of ('win32', 'win-amd64', 'win-arm32', 'win-arm64')
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> lxml

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

I tried installing lxml from [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/) but no matter whatever file I try it says `ERROR: lxml-4.9.0-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.` then I tried this command `py -m pip install -r requirements.txt Collecting gitpython==3.0.6` which in the log downloaded what I think is the lxml

```
Using cached GitPython-3.0.6-py3-none-any.whl (451 kB)
Collecting gitdb2
  Using cached gitdb2-4.0.2-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 kB)
Collecting lxml
  Downloading lxml-4.9.2-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (3.8 MB)
     ---------------------------------------- 3.8/3.8 MB 2.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting beautifulsoup4==4.8.2
  Using cached beautifulsoup4-4.8.2-py3-none-any.whl (106 kB)
Collecting requests
  Using cached requests-2.28.2-py3-none-any.whl (62 kB)
Collecting soupsieve>=1.2
  Using cached soupsieve-2.4-py3-none-any.whl (37 kB)
Collecting gitdb>=4.0.1
  Using cached gitdb-4.0.10-py3-none-any.whl (62 kB)
Collecting charset-normalizer<4,>=2
  Downloading charset_normalizer-3.0.1-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (96 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 96.0/96.0 kB 1.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting idna<4,>=2.5
  Using cached idna-3.4-py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
Collecting urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1
  Using cached urllib3-1.26.14-py2.py3-none-any.whl (140 kB)
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17
  Using cached certifi-2022.12.7-py3-none-any.whl (155 kB)
Collecting smmap<6,>=3.0.1
  Using cached smmap-5.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (24 kB)
Installing collected packages: charset-normalizer, urllib3, soupsieve, smmap, lxml, idna, certifi, requests, gitdb, beautifulsoup4, gitdb2, gitpython
Successfully installed beautifulsoup4-4.8.2 certifi-2022.12.7 charset-normalizer-3.0.1 gitdb-4.0.10 gitdb2-4.0.2 gitpython-3.0.6 idna-3.4 lxml-4.9.2 requests-2.28.2 smmap-5.0.0 soupsieve-2.4 urllib3-1.26.14
```

but my main command harwest still gives the above error of legacy-install-failure .

I also downloaded microsoft build tools without the optional stuff and its still not working

I have installed python 10 and 11 although in cmd it shows 10 only

I am at a loss, Please help

Answer (score 0):

I suspect these are the relevant messages from the output:,

> `python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully`
> Wheel did not finish (Wheel automates some of the package installation process, in this case `nileshsah/harwest-tool`).

> `error: --plat-name must be one of ('win32', 'win-amd64', 'win-arm32', 'win-arm64')`
> Wheel parameter `--plat-name` value is not one of the supported values, the package author specifies what platforms their package has been designed in this case 4 types of win systems)

> `This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.`
> Second confirmation it's not pip or wheel code fault

Conclusion, I suspect `nileshsah/harwest-tool` may not be compatible with your system. It is possible to [specify CPU Architecture of a Python package](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67564208/6345724), this may require careful thought on your part or trial and error (on a non-critical Python installation) to see if `nileshsah/harwest-tool` is compatible with your system.

Comment: Once you have the solution, please update the Question tags only to those that are relevant to your solution.

Comment: Thanks(for the welcome as well) I had this installed on the same pc but then after a windows update error had to reset. This is the first time I am getting this error.