# How to force a platform wheel using build and pyproject.toml?

Tags: python, setuptools, python-packaging, python-wheel, pep517

I am trying to force a Python3 non-universal wheel I'm building to be a platform wheel, despite not having any native build steps that happen during the distribution-packaging process.

The wheel will include an OS-specific shared library, but that library is built and copied into my package directory by a larger build system that my package knows nothing about. By the time my Python3 package is ready to be built into a wheel, my build system has already built the native shared library and copied it into the package directory.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45150304/how-to-force-a-python-wheel-to-be-platform-specific-when-building-it) SO post details a solution that works for the now-deprecated `setup.py` approach, but I'm unsure how to accomplish the same result using the new and now-standard `build` / `pyproject.toml` system:

```
mypackage/
  mypackage.py  # Uses platform.system and importlib to load the local OS-specific library
  pyproject.toml
  mysharedlib.so  # Or .dylib on macOS, or .dll on Windows
```

Based on the host OS performing the build, I would like the resulting wheel to be `manylinux`, `macos`, or `windows`.

I build with `python3 -m build --wheel`, and that always emits `mypackage-0.1-py3-none-any.whl`.

What do I have to change to force the build to emit a platform wheel?

Comment: I think maybe you can use the [`--config-setting`](https://pypa-build.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#python--m-build---config-setting) option, maybe `python -m build --config-setting=--plat-name=x86_64` or something like that.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at that. I'd prefer a solution that lets the wheel package name the platform based on the host OS, rather than having to duplicate it. I'm guessing there's a way to specify or override the `Distribution` class via `pyproject.toml` settings, where the technique described in the SO answer I linked in my question might apply?

Comment: I just used `--plat-name` as an example, I guess you can probably use other settings. -- Maybe this is related: https://github.com/pypa/build/issues/202

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update 2 Sept 2023:**
`-C=--build-option=--plat {your-platform-tag}` no longer works, so I added my preferred replacement to the end of the list.

==========

OK, after some research and reading of code, I can present a bit of information and a few solutions that might meet other people's needs, summarized here:

Firstly, `pyproject.toml` is not mutually exclusive from `setup.py`. `setuptools` will complain about deprecation if you create a distribution package via `python3 setup.py ...` and no `pyproject.toml` file is present.

However, `setup.py` is still around and available, but it's a mistake to duplicate project configuration values (`name`, `version`, etc). So, put as much as your package will allow inside your `pyproject.toml` file, and use `setup.py` for things like overriding the `Distribution` class, or overriding the `bdist_wheel` module, etc.

As far as creating platform wheels, there are a few approaches that work, with pros and cons:

1. Override the `bdist_wheel` command class in `setup.py` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45150383/16845) and set `self.root_is_pure` to False in the `finalize_options` override. This forces the python tag (e.g. `cp39`) to be set, along with the platform tag.
2. Override the `Distribution` class in `setup.py` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62668026/16845) and override `has_ext_modules()` to simply return True. This also forces the python and platform tags to be set.
3. Add an unused minimal extension module to your packaging definition, as described [here](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/ext_modules.html#building-extension-modules) and [here](https://github.com/numenta/nupic.core/pull/774/files). This lengthens the build process and adds a useless "dummy" shared library to be dragged along wherever your wheel goes.
4. **This solution appears to not work anymore!** Add the argument `-C=--build-option=--plat {your-platform-tag}` to the build invocation (for my case that's `python -m build -w -n`, for example). This leaves the Python tag untouched but you have to supply your own tag; there's no way to say "use whatever the native platform is". You can discover the exact platform tag with the command `wheel.bdist_wheel.get_platform(pathlib.Path('.'))` after importing the `pathlib` and `wheel.bdist_wheel` packages, but that can be cumbersome because `wheel` isn't a standard library package.
5. Simply rename your wheel from `mypkg-py3-none-any.whl` to `mypkg-py3-none-macosx_13_0_x86_64.whl`- it appears that the platform tag is only encoded into the filename, and not any of the package metadata that's generated during the distribution-package process.
6. Use the `wheel` package utility to update the tags, to turn the pure wheel into a platform wheel. `python -m wheel tags --platform-tag macosx_13_0_x86_64 mypkg-py3-none-any.whl` will emit a new platform wheel with the tags you want.

In the end I chose the final options because it required the least amount of work- no `setup.py` files need to be introduced solely to accomplish this, and the build logs make it clear that a platform wheel (not a pure wheel) is being created.

Comment: Same challenges here.  Did you script your #4 solution?  Would love to take a peek if  you have a link.

Comment: @gbarter https://gist.github.com/charlesnicholson/698d23aff66afbf091834100785aa84d is what I landed on. Hope it helps!

Comment: I updated the gist above to display my new preferred option, since the build_option thing stopped working abruptly.