i want exact filename dm_reverb-0.8.0-cp39-cp39-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl
I want to generate the exact filename
dm_reverb-0.8.0-cp39-cp39-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl
this is my setup.py file

setup(
    name='dm_reverb',
    version='0.8.0',
    description='this is a test file',
    author='atif',
    packages=find_packages(),
    install_requires=['wheel','bar'],  # Add any dependencies here if needed
    python_requires='==3.9',  # Explicitly set the Python version
)

init.py file
# dm_reverb_package/dm_reverb/__init__.py

def hello():
   print("Hello from dm_reverb!")

the installation command
python3 setup.py bdist_wheel --plat-name=manylinux2010_x86_64 --python-tag cp39-cp39
it is producing filename dm_reverb-0.8.0-cp39-cp39-none-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl
but i want this filename dm_reverb-0.8.0-cp39-cp39-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl
how to remove none

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45150383/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsetuptools%5D+platform+wheel
