# How to create a full wheel with abi tag?

Tags: python, setuptools, cpython, abi, python-wheel

Trying to create a wheel from an empty project, using this `setup.py`:

### setup.py

---

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(name='bla', version='1')
```

I invoke with `python setup.py bdist_wheel --python-tag py35 --plat-name linux_x86_64` and get 
***bla-1-py35-none-linux_x86_64.whl***

### My machine stats

---

```
python -V: Python 3.6.9
uname -p: x86_64
```

1. How to enforce abi? (make it ***bla-1-py35-cp35-linux_x86_64.whl***)
2. How to decide between py35 and cp35 in my python-tag?

Comment: Use Python 3.5 to build the wheel.

Comment: I guess it should be `--py-limited-api cp35`, but doesn't seem to have an effect in my quick tests.

Comment: I think "py" is supposed to denote a pure-Python implementation, so ABI is not really relevant for it. For the ABI to be truly relevant, it should be instead "cp", "pp", etc.

Answer (score 8):

After MUCH searching myself, I finally found a working solution in ['pip setup.py bdist_wheel' no longer builds forced non-pure wheels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35112511/pip-setup-py-bdist-wheel-no-longer-builds-forced-non-pure-wheels)

Basically, if setup.py believes you have a binary distribution, it will create a wheel with the specific version of python, the ABI, and the current architecture.  You can do that by overriding the 'has_ext_modules' function in the Distribution class.  As suggested by https://stackoverflow.com/users/5316090/py-j:

```
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools.dist import Distribution

DISTNAME = "packagename"
DESCRIPTION = ""
MAINTAINER = ""
MAINTAINER_EMAIL = ""
URL = ""
LICENSE = ""
DOWNLOAD_URL = ""
VERSION = '1.2'
PYTHON_VERSION = (2, 7)


# Tested with wheel v0.29.0
class BinaryDistribution(Distribution):
    """Distribution which always forces a binary package with platform name"""
    def has_ext_modules(foo):
        return True


setup(name=DISTNAME,
      description=DESCRIPTION,
      maintainer=MAINTAINER,
      maintainer_email=MAINTAINER_EMAIL,
      url=URL,
      license=LICENSE,
      download_url=DOWNLOAD_URL,
      version=VERSION,
      packages=["packagename"],

      # Include pre-compiled extension
      package_data={"packagename": ["_precompiled_extension.pyd"]},
      distclass=BinaryDistribution)
```

Then you run the setup.py file from whatever Python version/architecture you need, and it will create a platform-specific wheel for each.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer! It worked and saved me a ton of time!

Answer (score -1):

The ABI tag depends on your Python version. It will be automatically added to your wheel file name. The command `python setup.py bdist_wheel` is enough for building the wheel file.

To create wheel packages with different ABI tags, a simple way is to run different Python versions in different Docker containers.

[image]

The wheel packages I published to pypi.org

[image]

The pattern of my package name (package-cp(python version)-cp(python version)m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl) is a little bit from yours. You can't add cp35 to the package built using Python 3.6.

Comment: Have you tried this? This is clearly not true for my example

Comment: @CIsForCookies of course. This is how I built my wheels. I've published some wheel packages to pypi.org.