# python: create wheel from existing c extension

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, setup.py, python-wheel

Our build pipeline spits out an *.so / *.pyb python extension through pybind11. As a step in the pipeline I need to package the extension as a wheel for easy distribution through pip. I am trying to come up with a setup.py that takes the existing library and does not rely on re-compiling the binaries through the setup.py (so I really don't want [this](https://github.com/pybind/cmake_example/blob/master/setup.py)). It would require a **major** rewrite of the devops scripts.

When having a folder structure such as:

```
setup.py
my_module.cpython-39-darwin.so
```

A very basic setup.py can create a functioning wheel (`python setup.py bdist_wheel`):

```
setup(
    name = 'my_module', 
    version='0.9.102', 
    packages=["."],
    package_data={'': ['*.so', '*.pyi']},
)
```

Unfortunately, the wheel is missing the important python tag and platform name, etc: `my_module-0.9.102-py3-none-any.whl` vs. `my_module-0.9.102-cp39-cp39-macosx_10_13_x86_64.whl`

Setting --python-tag  and --plat-name works, setting --py-limited-api does not, however.

Through [research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60379212/how-to-create-a-full-wheel-with-abi-tag) I found that overwriting the `distclass` adds the correct tag again, but the `Root-Is-Purelib` is set back to false. This, unfortunately, creates a broken wheel when installing through pip as it puts the binary in a `my_module-0.9.102.data/purelib` folder...

Overwriting the `is_pure` seems to be ignored also:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages, Distribution

class BinaryDistribution(Distribution):
    def is_pure(self):
        return True

    def has_ext_modules(foo):
        return True

setup(
    name = 'my_module', 
    version='0.9.102', 
    packages=["."],
    package_data={'': ['*.so', '*.pyi']},
    distclass=BinaryDistribution
)
```

What else can I do to wrap my pre-compiled python libraries to wheels for distribution without rewriting lots of the build pipeline?

Comment: Have you read https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/compiling.html ?

Comment: Yes, but as said, I don’t want to compile the project again, the libs are already there

Comment: If you don't find a better way, you can always build the whl-file without using setuptools or disttools. It's just a zip-file.

Answer (score 1):

Not a perfect solution but a functional wheel is created when using the `wheel` module instead:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='my_module',
      packages=['my_module'],
      package_data={'': ['*.so', '*.pyi']},
      )
```

create wheel with:

```
pip install wheel
pip wheel .
```