# How to configure setuptools with setup.cfg to include platform name, python tag and ABI tag?

Tags: python, setuptools

Due to the console message of setup.py install is [deprecated](https://github.com/GNS3/gns3-server/issues/2013), I am in the middle of upgrading my existing setup.py install to the recommended setup.cfg with [build](https://pypa-build.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

My existing setup.py looks something like

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='pybindsample',
    version='0.1.0',
    packages=[''],
    package_data={'': ['pybindsample.so']},
    has_ext_modules=lambda: True,
)
```

My current translation looks like:

setup.cfg

```
[metadata]
name = pybindsample
version = 0.1.0

[options]
packages = . 

[options.package_data]
. = pybindsample.so
```

pyproject.toml

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
```

My question is how can I translate `has_ext_modules=lambda: True`? `has_ext_modules=lambda: True` is from the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64921892/3667089). Without this, after executing `python3 -m build --wheel` the file name of the generated wheel will become `pybindsample-0.1.0-py3-none-any.whl`, whereas my old `python3 setup.py bdist_wheel` will generate wheel with file name `pybindsample-0.1.0-cp39-cp39-macosx_11_0_x86_64.whl`. I have attempted

setup.cfg

```
[metadata]
name = pybindsample
version = 0.1.0

[options]
packages = . 
has_ext_modules=lambda: True,

[options.package_data]
. = pybindsample.so
```

but it still generates `pybindsample-0.1.0-py3-none-any.whl`, I also attempted

setup.cfg

```
[metadata]
name = pybindsample
version = 0.1.0

[options]
packages = . 

[options.package_data]
. = pybindsample.so

[bdist_wheel]
python-tag = c39
plat-name = macosx_11_0_x86_64
py-limited-api = c39
```

this generates `pybindsample-0.1.0-cp39-none-macosx_11_0_x86_64.whl`, and I couldn't figure out why the abi tag is still `none`.

What is the right way to configure setuptools with setup.cfg to include platform name, python tag, and ABI tag?