# Build a wheel with dll dependencies the right way

Tags: python, pip, python-wheel

I need some answers on how to setup my project correctly, including the setup.py, in order to make it include the dlls it depends on, but wheel doesn't seem to be getting them right from my configuration, and I'm not able to find a good example/documentation on how to do this the right way.

I have a project with the following structure:

```
myproj/
      __init__.py   <--this only does an import of proj.pyd
      lib/
         proj.pyd   <--the pyd is compiled, so it depends on the python version
         dep1.dll
         dep2.dll
         dep3.dll
setup.py
```

In setup.py I have

```
from setuptools import setup

# this is the package data (non - python files)
_package_data = ['lib/*.*']

setup(
    name='myproj',
    version='1.0.0',
    packages=['myproj'],
    url='an url',
    license='some license',
    author='author',
    description='description',
    package_data={'myproj':  _package_data},
    platforms='win',
    python_requires='~=3.8',
)
```

The configuration above actually builds myproj and I'm able to use it, but the wheel name does not reflect the platform nor the python version (myproj-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl), presumably because the only code it finds (in the **init**.py) is pure python. I can manually change the name, but doing it feels wrong.

I'm certainly doing something wrong, maybe building the pyd in a different process, for example, but I can't find a good reference on how to do all this the right way.

At minimum, I'd like to understand why `python setup.py bdist_wheel` is ignoring my "python_requires" and "platforms" settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue, but managed to solve it using the answer and comments here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24793171

You can tell setup to be distribution specific by either passing `distclass` with a `setuptools.Distribution` object or `has_ext_modules=lambda : True` as arguments to `setup()`. The latter is simpler in this case.

Your `setup.py` would be:

```
from setuptools import setup

# this is the package data (non - python files)
_package_data = ['lib/*.*']

setup(
    name='myproj',
    version='1.0.0',
    packages=['myproj'],
    url='an url',
    license='some license',
    author='author',
    description='description',
    package_data={'myproj':  _package_data},
    platforms='win',
    python_requires='~=3.8',
    has_ext_modules=lambda : True,  # <-- This line is added
)
```