# How to packup a pypi ".whl" file for version-specific systems?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I want to upload some open source code to pypi which contains binary content written in cython. This means that if I want to save users from compile source code themselfs, I need to release different binary libs for different system versions and python versions.

As I tested, pypi can accept the same version (say `0.1.0`) of `".whl"` files as long as they have different file names. However, no matter what system I'm on, the file names I pack out are all the same, for example `mypackage-0.1.0-py3-none-any.whl`, which I want them to show up as `mypackage-0.1.0-py39-py39-win_amd64.whl`

What should I do? thanks!

====

Edit:

My build up system is a very simple copy from official doc, here's all of it.

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name="hash-c", 
    version='0.0.1',
    author="REDMOND",
    description='Some description',
    long_description='Some description',
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    packages = find_packages(),
    package_data={
        'hash_c': ['libc.cp38_amd64.pyd',],
    },
    install_requires = [],
    classifiers=[
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.7',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.8',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.9',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3 :: Only',
        'License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License',
        'Operating System :: POSIX :: Linux',
        'Operating System :: Microsoft :: Windows',
    ],
    python_requires='>=3.6',
    keywords=["hash-c"]
)
```

I placed a compile dll file in folder tree:

```
.
├── hash_c
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── lib.cp38_amd64.pyd
└── setup.py
```

Comment: Please show your `setup.py`. Better, all your code. Even better in a Git repository. Also show commands you use to build wheels.

Comment: Try this trick: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24793171/7976758

Comment: @phd Thanks! I didn't find much useful information on google myself