# How can I add platform-specific dynamic libraries to Python wheel, with independent binaries for Windows and Linux?

Tags: python, shared-libraries, blender, python-packaging, python-wheel

I really want to use blender compiled as a python package in my project. I was thinking about attaching already compiled blender binaries to the wheel on PyPI, as compilation is already complicated on its own and requires a huge amount of dependencies. However, I'm new to wheels and I'm not sure how to configure setup.py to make it use different binaries depending on the target platform (How to make two wheels, independent for each platform) and whether the PyPI endpoint will accept them.

I will be very grateful for the answers and/or links to some documentation that describes such usage of wheels because I was not able to correctly formulate the questions to Google on my own.

I'd also like to add that I have already found a method to attach binaries at all [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24071491/how-can-i-make-a-python-wheel-from-an-existing-native-library) and a way to create platform-specific wheels [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45150304/how-to-force-a-python-wheel-to-be-platform-specific-when-building-it) but those do not solve my problem, or I'm not aware they do.