# compile CPython extension written in Zig on Windows

Tags: windows, visual-c++, cpython, zig

Zig is able to import C libraries and therefore it can be used to write a CPython extension and compile it. This is potentially really useful for me.

Here's my simple.zig Python extension

```
const py = @cImport({
    @cDefine("PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN", {});
    @cInclude("Python.h");
});
const std = @import("std");
const print = std.debug.print;

const PyObject = py.PyObject;
const PyMethodDef = py.PyMethodDef;
const PyModuleDef = py.PyModuleDef;
const PyModuleDef_Base = py.PyModuleDef_Base;
const Py_BuildValue = py.Py_BuildValue;
const PyModule_Create = py.PyModule_Create;
const METH_NOARGS = py.METH_NOARGS;

fn hello(self: [*c]PyObject, args: [*c]PyObject) callconv(.C) [*]PyObject {
    _ = self;
    _ = args;
    print("welcom to ziglang\n", .{});
    return Py_BuildValue("");
}

var Methods = [_]PyMethodDef{
    PyMethodDef{
        .ml_name = "hello",
        .ml_meth = hello,
        .ml_flags = METH_NOARGS,
        .ml_doc = null,
    },
    PyMethodDef{
        .ml_name = null,
        .ml_meth = null,
        .ml_flags = 0,
        .ml_doc = null,
    },
};

var module = PyModuleDef{
    .m_base = PyModuleDef_Base{
        .ob_base = PyObject{
            .ob_refcnt = 1,
            .ob_type = null,
        },
        .m_init = null,
        .m_index = 0,
        .m_copy = null,
    },
    .m_name = "simple",
    .m_doc = null,
    .m_size = -1,
    .m_methods = &Methods,
    .m_slots = null,
    .m_traverse = null,
    .m_clear = null,
    .m_free = null,
};

pub export fn PyInit_simple() [*]PyObject {
    return PyModule_Create(&module);
}
```

When I compile my CPython extension written in Zig with the Zig compiler, Python is unable to import the DLL. I am using Windows 10.

```
zig build-lib -lc -dynamic -target x86_64-windows-msvc -I"C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\include" -L"C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\libs" -l"python39" simple.zig
```

When I try to import simple.dll, Python says no module found. I am using the os module to add the directory containing my extension DLL to the extension search locations, as I believe is required on Windows since Python 3.8.

```
import os
os.add_dll_directory(r"C:\Users\me\my_zig_project")
import simple
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'simple'
```

I suspect the problem is that CPython on Windows is compiled with the MSVC compiler (version of MSVC depends on Python version) and the Zig compiler is not compatible somehow even though I specify target environment as Windows MSVC.

Is there a way to compile a CPython extension written in Zig to run on Windows?

A minimal example would be greatly appreciated if it is possible.

Comment: [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Add some minimal code, build and run commands, and output.

Comment: “A minimal example would be greatly appreciated if it is possible”, back to you: Please show us what you’re trying to do – a minimal module written in zig, how you’re compiling it, and how you’re trying to use it from python.

Comment: @CristiFati thanks for the guide.

Comment: @Cubic hopefully I've addressed your points now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having seen this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9q-LHP7cMfg I realized all I needed was to rename my simple.dll to simple.pyd

Here's a working minimal example. Create simple.zig as below

```
const py = @cImport({
    @cDefine("PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN", {});
    @cInclude("Python.h");
});
const std = @import("std");
const print = std.debug.print;

const PyObject = py.PyObject;
const PyMethodDef = py.PyMethodDef;
const PyModuleDef = py.PyModuleDef;
const PyModuleDef_Base = py.PyModuleDef_Base;
const Py_BuildValue = py.Py_BuildValue;
const PyModule_Create = py.PyModule_Create;
const METH_NOARGS = py.METH_NOARGS;

fn hello(self: [*c]PyObject, args: [*c]PyObject) callconv(.C) [*]PyObject {
    _ = self;
    _ = args;
    print("welcome to ziglang\n", .{});
    return Py_BuildValue("");
}

var Methods = [_]PyMethodDef{
    PyMethodDef{
        .ml_name = "hello",
        .ml_meth = hello,
        .ml_flags = METH_NOARGS,
        .ml_doc = null,
    },
    PyMethodDef{
        .ml_name = null,
        .ml_meth = null,
        .ml_flags = 0,
        .ml_doc = null,
    },
};

var module = PyModuleDef{
    .m_base = PyModuleDef_Base{
        .ob_base = PyObject{
            .ob_refcnt = 1,
            .ob_type = null,
        },
        .m_init = null,
        .m_index = 0,
        .m_copy = null,
    },
    .m_name = "simple",
    .m_doc = null,
    .m_size = -1,
    .m_methods = &Methods,
    .m_slots = null,
    .m_traverse = null,
    .m_clear = null,
    .m_free = null,
};

pub export fn PyInit_simple() [*]PyObject {
    return PyModule_Create(&module);
}
```

Build simple.zig to get simple.dll

```
zig build-lib -lc -dynamic -I"<directory containing Python.h>" -L"<directory containing python3.lib>" -l"python3" simple.zig
```

**Rename simple.dll to simple.pyd**

Run python.exe in the directory containing simple.pyd (python.exe's version 3.X must match the python3.lib you linked against)

```
>>> import simple
>>> simple.hello()
welcome to ziglang
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't been able to use the typical `setuptools` methods to create Python modules using Zig, but I have been able to use the [`wheel`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_wheel/) module to create modules which link DLL files compiled with Zig that can then be installed with Pip. Here is a minimal example.

You will need to install the [`setuptools`](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/index.html) and [`wheel`](https://wheel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) modules first if they aren't already installed on your system. I took inspiration from [this informative SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24793171/6879826).

Create a directory structure like this:

```
hello_zig_mod/
|
|-- setup.py
|
|-- hello/
    |
    |-- __init__.py
    |
    |-- hello.zig
```

The `hello.zig` file is the Zig code that will be compiled to a DLL:

```
const std = @import("std");

pub export fn message(msg: [*c]const u8) void {
    std.debug.print("Hello, {s}!\n", .{std.mem.span(msg)});
}
```

The `__init__.py` file is a Python file used to initialize the module. It links to the DLL and wraps the `message` function found there in a Python function:

```py
from ctypes import *
import os
lib_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'hello.dll')
lib = CDLL(lib_path)

def message(msg):
    lib.message(bytes(msg, 'utf-8'))
```

The `setup.py` file is used to build a wheel that can be installed by Pip. You can read more about the details of this file at [the answer I linked above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24793171/6879826).

```py
from setuptools import setup, Distribution

class BinaryDistribution(Distribution):
    def has_ext_modules(foo):
        return True

setup(
    name="hello",
    packages=['hello'],
    package_data={
        'hello':['hello.dll'],
    },
    distclass=BinaryDistribution
)
```

Go into the `hello/` directory and build a dynamic library with the Zig compiler.

```
> zig build-lib .\hello.zig -dynamic
```

This will build the DLL along with some other artifacts. Now go back to the `hello_zig_mod` directory and build the wheel:

```
> python setup.py bdist_wheel
```

This will build the wheel in `dist\` as a `.whl` file along with other artifacts. You can now finally install the wheel with Pip:

```
> pip install .\dist\hello-0.0.0-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl
```

Checking in a Python REPL:

```
>>> import hello
>>> hello.message("Zig Module")
Hello, Zig Module!
```

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping to build an extension without using any other Python tools like setuptools but thanks for your example - it's a valid way to do it and has guided me to the missing piece of the puzzle, that I needed to rename simple.dll to simple.pyd. I need to include the -lc flag to the zig build-lib command so that it includes libc else I get io.h not found.